# SQL Server DIFF backup prompts for files to be overwritten

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups, backups

I am using SQL Server Express and I have a stored procedure for taking backups which I took from Microsoft: [How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se)

Then I use Windows Task Scheduler for taking the backups.

I have a task running on 2 AM which takes a full backup using command:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER\MSSQLEXPRESS -E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='C:\Backups\SQL\TEMP\', @backupType='F'"
```

Then from 2.30 AM I take a differential backup every hour using command:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER\MSSQLEXPRESS -E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='C:\Backups\SQL\TEMP\', @backupType='D'"
```

Now here I have a problem, the full backup works but after that I see no new added backup files in my folder. When I open the server I see a command prompt from the differential backup running asking to overwrite the FULL backup files.
I click A from ALL and then it works. The hour after again, a command prompt to overwrite previous DIFF and FULL backup files.

How can I set this to always be ALL or how can I disable this?

Comment: Looking at that script it generates a unique filename per-backup and uses WITH INIT which allows overwrite so something else is wrong. No T-SQL will prompt you for anything, its not interactive, what is actually prompting you to overwrite?  What happens if you run the command manually outside of the Task Scheduler?

Comment: Ok I have found the problem. After every DIFF backup I have a xcopy command which copies all the files to another location. This was causing the command prompt to ask if files needs to be overwritten. My mistake!